# Flutter Web - Scrolling is very laggy for large number of images

Tags: image, flutter, web, scroll

I have a Flutter website built on channel beta that is used for uploading large images.
When testing on Chrome, scrolling down when there are large number of image rows it is extremely laggy.

Below is a sample reproduction of the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dropzone/flutter_dropzone.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  DropzoneViewController controller1;
  String message1 = 'Drop something here';
  bool highlighted1 = false;
  List assets = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Dropzone example'),
          ),
          body: ListView(
            children: [
              if (assets.length > 0)
                _showAssets(assets)
              else
                buildZone1(context),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    color: Colors.greenAccent,
                    child: Text('Browse files'),
                    onPressed: () =>
                        controller1.pickFiles(multiple: true).then((files) {
                      files.forEach((file) {
                        controller1.createFileUrl(file).then((url) {
                          setState(() {
                            print('in set state');
                            assets.add(url);
                          });
                        });
                      });
                    }),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(height: 400, color: Colors.lightGreen),
              Container(height: 400, color: Colors.redAccent),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
  Widget _showAssets(List assets) {
    //print(assets);
    return Wrap(
      children: assets.map((asset) {
        return Container(
          height: 150,
          child: Image.network(asset),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }

  Widget buildZone1(BuildContext context) => Builder(
        builder: (context) => Container(
          height: 200,
          child: DropzoneView(
            operation: DragOperation.copy,
            cursor: CursorType.grab,
            onCreated: (ctrl) => controller1 = ctrl,
            onLoaded: () => print('Zone 1 loaded'),
            onError: (ev) => print('Zone 1 error: $ev'),
            onHover: () {
              setState(() => highlighted1 = true);
              //print('Zone 1 hovered');
            },
            onLeave: () {
              setState(() => highlighted1 = false);
              //print('Zone 1 left');
            },
            onDrop: (ev) {
              print('Zone 1 drop: ${ev.name}');
              setState(() {
                print('in set state');
                message1 = '${ev.name} dropped';
                highlighted1 = false;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
name: file_upload
description: A new Flutter project.


publish_to: 'none' 

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_dropzone: ^1.0.9


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

To reproduce

- Click on Browse files and select over 50 to 100 images of over 2MB to display over 10 rows
- Try to scroll down when the images are visible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not lazily building the pictures. Use `ListView.builder` instead.

The documentation states in regard to the default `ListView` constructor:

> This constructor is appropriate for list views with a small number of children because constructing the List requires doing work for every child that could possibly be displayed in the list view instead of just those children that are actually visible.

With 50 to 100 **2MB** images, it would be understandable that your computer is having a hard time.

The documentation states that the `ListView.builder` constructor builds children on demand.

> The ListView.builder constructor takes an IndexedWidgetBuilder, which builds the children on demand. This constructor is appropriate for list views with a large (or infinite) number of children because the builder is called only for those children that are actually visible.

Ex.

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (assets.length > 0) {
      if (assets[index] == null) {
        return null;
      }
      return Container(
        height: 150,
        child: Image.network(assets[index]),
      );
    }
    else {
      if(index > 0) {
        return null;
      }
      return buildZone1(context);
    }
  },
)
```

Comment: Spot on! The lazy building of the List indeed helps the scrolling. My production code uses GridView.builder and I am also using cacheExtent to make the scrolling experience smoother. Many thanks!. Sorry for the late up tick.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by compressing and downsizing the images to the lowest possible form while maintaining fidelity. that compressed images showed major improvements in the lag specially while scrolling